# jumping / alternating sequence that will ordner rows in dataframe

Tags: r, sequence, seq

lets say i have a ds with rows:

```
cat
dog
lion
miau
wuff
roarr
```

i want to order them in a sequence

```
cat
miau
dog
wuff
lion
roarr
```

in order to do that i need to order it with a sequence

```
1 4 2 5 3 6
```

Lets take a more general example with arbitrary n:

```
n <- 10

ds < data.frame(col=c(paste0(letters[1:n],1),paste0(letters[1:n],2)),stringsAsFactors = F)

ds[,] <- ds[mySeq,]
```

## How to generate that sequence (mySeq) for all kind of n ?

```
> ds
   col
1   a1
2   b1
3   c1
4   d1
5   e1
6   f1
7   g1
8   h1
9   i1
10  j1
11  a2
12  b2
13  c2
14  d2
15  e2
16  f2
17  g2
18  h2
19  i2
20  j2
>
```

edit:
i could imagine to zip the sequences 1:(nrow(ds)/2) and (nrow(ds)/2+1):nrow(ds).
So if n gets higher i need to zip alot of seqs. Not really practical.

The gtools mixedsort() wont work with "random" rows:

```
set.seed(1337)
MHmakeRandomString <- function(n=1, lenght=12)
{
  randomString <- c(1:n)                  # initialize vector
  for (i in 1:n)
  {
    randomString[i] <- paste(sample(c(0:9, letters, LETTERS),
                                    lenght, replace=TRUE),
                             collapse="")
  }
  return(randomString)
}

ds <- data.frame(col=c(paste0(MHmakeRandomString(n),1),paste0(MHmakeRandomString(n),2)),stringsAsFactors = F)

dso <- mixedsort(ds)
```

## I think i do need that sequence!

i updated my first mini example!

Comment: `ds$col[order(gsub('\\D+', '', ds$col))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's another approach, trying to generate the numerical sequence based on it's underlying patterns. This means no string operations.

```
 sequence_generator  <- function(n, nrow){
  base_seq=rep(1:n,each=nrow/n)
  res=base_seq+seq(0,(nrow/n)-1)*n
  res
}

sequence_generator(3,6)
# [1] 1 4 2 5 3 6
sequence_generator(10,20)
#[1]  1 11  2 12  3 13  4 14  5 15  6 16  7 17  8 18  9 19 10 20
```

Comment: thank you. this is what i was looking for. thats a gerneral solution working everytime. If anyone has a shorter version im happy to see.

Comment: What do you mean with 'a shorter version'? It can be written as a oneliner, but I put it into a function for demonstration purposes.

Comment: The n could be taken out of the argument list and be defined as n <- nrow/2

Comment: Not really, because in this context n is the number of 'blocks'. As such, it can be any value.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub`

```
ds[order(sub("\\D+", "", ds[,1])), , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: i guess the OP needs it as `a1,b1,a2,b2` etc. if Im not wrong

Comment: @AndreElrico  You showed an example earlier and this works for that.  If you want to keep changing your post, go ahead and do that.  I didn't say that it would work for all the cases

Comment: sorry i should have written, that im looking for a general solution that works everytime no matter that the content in the row is!

Comment: @AndreElrico  If you are looking for a general case, the number of elements should also be random instead of fixed

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
n <- 10
ds <- data.frame(col=c(paste0(letters[1:n],1), paste0(letters[1:n],2)), stringsAsFactors = F)
mySeq <- order(substr(ds$col,1,1), substr(ds$col,2,2))
ds <- ds[mySeq,]
```

Comment: you are again using the "clean" letters. look at my edit with the random strings:

Comment: But what do you want exactly with these random rows?? How should they end up being sorted then? Just by the last character?

Comment: @AndreElrico in that case `mySeq <- order(substr(ds$col,nchar(ds$col),nchar(ds$col)))` will do